# How to update a local git pull-request?

Tags: git

I want to update a local git pull request.

To check out a local git pull request I usually do the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/me/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
gh pr checkout 4
```

But then someone makes updates to that pull request number 4, and what I usually do is the following:

```
cd ..
rm -rf myrepo
git clone https://github.com/me/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
gh pr checkout 4
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

And can this all be done without the use of `gh`?

Comment: I don't know much about `gh` but your pr is just a branch that's in consideration for merging. You should be able to just fetch/pull that branch to update if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, like @JeffMercado said - run `git pull`.